# I can't get data from Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some issues creating a login activity. 
Even though I put the right username (123456) and password (123456789).

I made sure to put the getText() method inside onLogin but I always get the message "login failed" and so I assume I don't get any data from EditText, and so I can't see what's wrong.
this login java class:

```html
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText UsernameEt;
    private EditText PasswordEt;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        UsernameEt=findViewById(R.id.username);
        PasswordEt=findViewById(R.id.password);
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");


    }

    public void onLogin(View view) {
        String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
        String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";

        //BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        //backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);

        if(username=="123456" && password=="123456789"){

            alertDialog.setMessage("Login success");
            alertDialog.show();

       } else {

            alertDialog.setMessage("Login failed");
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }


}
```

and this is the login xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="IPN"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            style="@style/DefaultButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradiant"
            android:onClick="onLogin"
            android:text="@string/login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(username.equals("123456") && password.equals("123456789"){ 
// login true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
username.getText().toString().contentEquals("123456") && password.getText().toString().contentEquals("123456789")
```